# how to rename file on upload custom component joomla 3

Tags: component, mvc, file-upload

I recently create a custom component with [Component Creator](http://component-creator.com/), and I have a form in admin area that uploads file...

But I can't upload files with same name it's going to replace the previous file, now I want to rename the file on upload not moving them is the best idea?

I don't know how to rename a file on upload, I've used the `save()` function in my component controller but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not simply check to see if a file of that name already exists and if so, add a `_1` on to the end. Of course, you will have to increment the number in a `while` loop

Comment: could you please share the code and say where should i put it .... in component controller ??? if that's works it's a big help, thanks

Comment: check this here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909324/add-file-uploader-to-joomla-admin-component

Comment: @Joomla, I'd recommend linking to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19431372/1362108 ....The answers that have been upvoted are using old, deprecated methods

Comment: Instead of using a while loop in increment the number just use the current unix timestamp. It would be nearly impossible to have duplicates using that method. <?php echo $filename.'_'.time().'.extension';?>

Comment: @TerryCarter can you please write the whole code for component controller that only renames the file on/before upload, please

Comment: please someone write the whole code for joomla 3, i'm really stock :(( , thanks

Comment: its already answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911333/how-to-change-filename-on-uploading-on-joomla-custom-component-mvc/35933745#35933745

Comment: @Joomler , I asked that question and it won't work for me...

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of what you have already tried. None of us can even begin to write your controller for you, or are willing to try, without seeing what you have already attempted. Not know how your form is setup also makes things a bit difficult for us. My recommendation would be to post your form code, and what you have for your save function in your controller. Maybe we can piece something together for you are that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the filename of your `save()` function, then split the name into two halves on the first occurring dot.

```
$img_name = $file['name'];  
$img = explode(".", $img_name, 2);  
$file['name'] = $img[0].'_'.rand().'.'.$img[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

To make unique file name of uploaded file, you can concatenate file name with current time-stamp in save() function in your component.
For example:

`$fileName = $fileName . '_' . time();`

Hope this will help you.